# Detect menu bar tracking

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to detect when tracking has started on the menu bar, including on menu extras? I have a window that I want to have behave like a menu, so it needs to be hidden when any other menu is displayed.

Comment: No way you can achieve what you need by overriding NSPopupButton or NSMenuItem?

Comment: Nope. My window also has popup menus, which IIUC you can't do while menu tracking is already going on.